# If the pointwise limit of a function is not $\;L^2-$integrable then what about the function itself?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, improper-integrals

Let $\;f(x):\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n\;$ be a smooth function such that $\;\vert f(x)-l_{\pm} \vert \le e^{-k\vert x \vert}\;$ as $\;\vert x \vert \to \infty\;$ ($\;k\;$ is a positive constant and $\;l_{-} \neq l_{+}\;$).

The above exponential estimate simply says that: $\;\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x) =l_{-}\;,\;\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)=l_{+}\;$

**I want to show $\; \int_{0}^{+\infty} {\vert f(x)-l_{-} \vert}^2\;dx\;=\infty\;$**

I observed that $\;{\vert f(x) -l_{-} \vert}^2 \to {\vert l_{+} -l_{-} \vert}^2\;$ as $\;x \to +\infty\;$ and it is well known that $\;\int_{0}^{+\infty} {\vert l_{+} -l_{-} \vert}^2\;dx=\infty\;$. I wonder if I could use this fact somehow in order to prove that also $\; \int_{0}^{+\infty} {\vert f(x)-l_{-} \vert}^2\;dx\;=\infty\;$

Any help would be valuable!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you assuming $l_-\neq l_+$? Because otherwise $\int_0^{\infty}|l_+-l_-|^2dx = 0$

Comment: @LorenzoQ. I forgot to mention that. I just edited it

Comment: Hint: Minkowski's inequality.

Comment: @LorenzoQ. If I use MInkowski's inequality then I conclude to  $\;\int_{0}^{+\infty} {\vert f(x)-l_{-} \vert}^2\;dx\;\le \int_{0}^{+\infty} {\vert f(x)-l_{+} \vert}^2\;dx\;+\int_{0}^{+\infty} {\vert l_{+}-l_{-} \vert}^2\;dx\; =\infty\;$ but how can I be sure that $\;\int_{0}^{+\infty} {\vert f(x)-l_{-} \vert}^2\;dx=\infty\;$ since in this case I've found a bound $\;\le \infty\;$ and not $\;\ge \infty\;$?

Comment: You should use it like this: $\|l_--l_+\|\leq \|f-l_-\|+\|l_+-f\| $.

Comment: @LorenzoQ. Thanks a lot! I've been stuck!

Comment: @LorenzoQ. excuse me, but as I was trying the hint you suggested, a (maybe silly) question came to my mind: In order to use Minkowski's inequality shouldn't $\;f-l_{-}\;$ and $\;l_{+}-f\;$ belong to $\;L^2\;$?

Comment: The argument is by contradiction: if $f-l_-\in L^2$, then by the inequality $l_--l_+\in L^2$ too.

Comment: @LorenzoQ. You've no idea how much you helped me. Thanks again. Have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $l_+ \ne l_-$, then $c:=|l_+- l_-|^2>0$. From $\;{\vert f(x) -l_{-} \vert}^2 \to {\vert l_{+} -l_{-} \vert}^2\;$ as $x \to \infty$ we get a number $x_0>0$ such that

$\;{\vert f(x) -l_{-} \vert}^2  \ge c/2;$ for $x \ge x_0$.

Hence $\; \int_{0}^{+\infty} {\vert f(x)-l_{-} \vert}^2\;dx \ge \; \int_{x_0}^{+\infty} {\vert f(x)-l_{-} \vert}^2\;dx \ge \int_{x_0}^{+\infty} \frac{c}{2}dx= \infty$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I like your way too!